# Error when trying to write then read a XML file in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

EDITED : Adding all the informations I gathered since I posted this.

Hi stackers !
I'm trying for the first time to do a Metro style windows phone 8 app using Visual Studio 2013 and the WP8 SDK.

This app should be able to store a few data from the users in XML files stored in the app folder.

Here is what it should do :

The user use the app the normal way, and then saves data. I want to add it in a dataFile.xml file that is already created with only the xml declaration line and a root element. Then, if the user want to see what he saved, the app should get the data in the XML file and display it.

Here is the basic XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<itemList>

</itemList>
```

And the code where I write the data : (Modifications from edit here)

```
var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Saves\\itemList.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, store); //Where store is my definition of IsolatedStorageFile
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(isoFileStream);
                    var newItem = new XElement("Item",
                            new XElement("Name", ItemName.Text),
                            //all other elements here
                            new XElement("Method", method));
        xDoc.Root.Add(newItem);
        xDoc.Root.Save(isoFileStream);
        isoFileStream.Close();
```

Thanks to the IsolatedStorage and the ISETool.exe, I was able to retrieve the xml file after writing inside it using the code above. Here is the result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <itemList></itemList><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <itemList>
        <Item>
            <Name>My Item</Name>
            <Method>Item method</Method>
        </Item>
    </itemList>
```

So, to resume, the code loaded the xml file shown above, detected the root element using xDoc.Root, and added the item inside it. BUT, when saving, it recreates the XML declaration and the root element, making the file structure incorrect, so unusable. Why ? Good question. How to fix it ? That's what I would love to know.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Well have you had a look at what the file looks like after you've written it? I suspect it's basically two XML files stuck together - you need to go back to the start of the stream before writing, or (better IMO), read the file, close the stream, then reopen for writing. (In fact, just `XDocument.Load("Saves/itemList.xml")` and later `doc.Save("Saves/itemList.xml")` may well work, if those calls are supported under WP8.)

Comment: You can access the local storage of your deployed app on your device or emulator using the phone powertools. http://wptools.codeplex.com/ I find them helpful to check what is actually written to file :-)

Comment: @JonSkeet I actually tried not to use a fileStream, it was working for loading, but not for saving, saying it can't use a string instead of a writer, so I tried with a fileStream. 

I would love to try the power tools, if it wasn't crashing everytime I launch it with admin rights, and not displaying any emulator if not launched with admin rights.. 

I'll try to find a solution to display the xml content.

Comment: I tried to put the XML content into a TextBlock using xDoc.ToString(); to see what happen. As it's intelligent, it only shows the content, not the XML declaration (I tried to access it before doing any modification using ToString, it worked, and stop working right after the first modification). 

And it seems to write correctly the first item added : 

`<itemList>
    <item>
        <Name>ItemName</Name>
        <Number>1</Number>
        ...Other elements...
    </item>
</itemList>`

It must be messing with the declaration, but I can't figure out why..

Comment: Content of the XML file after the save added by editing the initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to deal with this, so I'm answering my own question, in case someone have the same problem.

The problem was here :

```
xDoc.Root.Save(isoFileStream);
```

This saves the XDocument formatted in the code using the file stream used to load the previous content of the XML file. But the XDocument.Save function is made to format a XML file to be usable even if the file was empty. So, it writes the data at the end of the file, making the structure incorrect by adding two declarations.

The solution was to gather the XML content in a var xDoc by using XDocument.load(fileStream), then close the stream and open a new one with the FileMode option set to Create, to overwrite the existing file :

```
var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Saves\\itemList.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, store);
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(isoFileStream);
isoFileStream.Close();
isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Saves\\itemList.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, store);
                    var newItem = new XElement("Item",
                            new XElement("Name", ItemName.Text),
                            //all other elements here
                            new XElement("Method", method));
        xDoc.Root.Add(newItem);
        xDoc.Save(isoFileStream);
        isoFileStream.Close();
```

This is working perfectly using this. Thanks to the ones who answered for their help :)